# how to remove bluish color border in opera on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, opera

Does anyone know how can I remove a blue color border which I am getting on Opera browser when I am clicking to the button.

My button has a dropdown over it

```
 <div class="dropdown tobeaddedtodropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle tobeaddedtobutton" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">  
    SELECT 
   </button>
  <input type="hidden" id="serving_style_id" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" id="serving_style_name" value="0">
  <span class="caret downarrow"></span>
  <ul id="step1ul" class="dropdown-menu tobeaddedtoul" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"style="background-color:transparent" value="1"  data-image="rtd"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"style="background-color:transparent" value="2"  data-image="tea_bag"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"style="background-color:transparent" value="3" data-image="rtd"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

One of the answer with `outline:none;`didn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove button outline in Opera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560862/how-to-remove-button-outline-in-opera)

Comment: this is not helping me

Comment: Please provide a fiddle (or at least an image) and/or your related css if any. Also in the title you say chrome but then you wrote opera, is the problem present in both?

Comment: have you tried `border:none;`?

Comment: that didn't help either @AdityaParab

Comment: How about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677467/how-to-disable-login-password-highlighting-in-opera)?

Comment: @JanTuroň nah this either, I don't know what's missing.
I read the most upvoted question there and it says not possible! :/

Comment: @Suraj: `outline:none; border:none;` is the real solution to this problem. Make sure, these properties are not getting inherited from some parent element. You can verify this by putting `outline:none !important;` on your button's CSS.

Comment: OMG, important has done the trick. Whatta shame man. 1 hour and turns out this was the solution.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

outline:none; is the solution ti this:
go and inspect the element and check if any other css is over-riding outline :none;
Further also try addinf !important to outline none and write the selector in a correct manner....
Hope this helps it would be better if you could provide your css in the question asked

Thanks!

Comment: `outline: none !important; border:none !important;`

the solution. 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px #fff !important;
```

This worked perfectly for me (for Opera select)